Monitor has different sharpness
The left part of my monitor has a sharp display. But the right one doesn't.
Left is okay:

But the right one has "purplish extra pixels" on top and bottom of the line:

Is it my monitor issue?
Note: these are images of an underscore being displayed on left and right parts of my monitor

It might indeed be the monitor, but it could also be due to the cable, or to settings such as Windows ClearType. Try using the display with another PC and another cable, to eliminate those. Also, try changing refresh rate and be sure to use monitor's native resolution.

Why not bring up a full screen test image with different line thicknesses & inspect it? It would also help if you said what monitor & how it is driven.
